# Is there any good reason to make a skill legendary?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know that making a skill legendary can allow you to level up more/faster but is there any other reason, it seems like that just takes away valuable skills. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason to Legendary a skill tree is, as you said, to allow the player to level indefinitely. Originally, you could only level up until all your skills were maxed, and then you would stop leveling up. This restricted players from reaching the levels necessary to unlock certain late-game spells, so the devs changed it to remove the level cap rather than lowering the levels required for those spells. In doing this, the devs also essentially made it possible to endlessly expand your magicka, health, and stamina limits (and therefore, with the latter, your carrying capacity). I have seen players devote so much time and energy to a single save game, that they can sprint the whole way from Solitude to Riften, casting Flames nonstop the entire trip.
Now, many players rely *only* on a few skill trees in a playthrough. For example, most of the time, I never use heavy armour or smithing. In the old system, this would have meant I was level capped even earlier than other players might have, unless I decided to start working on those skill trees, which I would rarely even *consider* doing. In the new system, I can completely abandon and ignore any skill trees that I do not wish to use in a save game, and still level endlessly.

Now, you specifically asked if there was any *other* reason to Legendary a skill. And the answer is: Yes!! There are now real perks to Legendarying a skill tree. When you make a skill Legendary, you unlock a permanent bonus to actions that rely on that skill tree, as well as an XP boost from those actions. Some mods and CC addons add other useful things to the Legendary option, but the base game and DLCs only have those two perks.

Comment: "permanent bonus to actions that rely on that skill tree, as well as an XP boost" <- Are you sure that's in vanilla Skyrim? I can't find any reference to that bonus on UESP or Wikia. I'm making legendary skills all the time (I'm level 133 right now), so I'd reeeeally be interested in learning more about that bonus :)

Comment: @AJPerez the bonus is very slight, and it's simply an effectiveness boost; Legendarying, say, Destruction makes all destruction spells deal slightly more damage or use less magicka than before. It's barely a noticeable difference, and it's not actually *said* anywhere in the game, but it's in the files